# Generalization of chain rule to tensors

Tags: matrices, multivariable-calculus, tensors

Are there any generalization of chain rule of differentiation to tensors? For example, how can I differentiate f(g(X)) where:
$g: Matrix(d_1, d_2) \to Matrix(d_3, d_4)$ and $f: Matrix(d_3, d_4) \to Matrix (d_5, d_6)$.

P.S. I understand how to compute derivative, I want a rule which takes a tensor derivative of f and a tensor derivative of g and combines them in a short step.

Comment: I presume "$Matrix(d_1,d_2)$" is the set of real $d_1\times d_2$ matrices? Then these are vector spaces, so you can just treat them as vector spaces.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I understand how to differentiate them. I want an easy way to do this in tensor form.

Answer (score 1):

Use Leibniz' Rule 
$$(M_{ij}N_{jk})_{,r}=M_{ij,r}N_{jk}+M_{ij}N_{jk,r}$$ 
where ${}_{,r}$ means differentiation. One writes $M_{ij}N_{jk}$ (for matrix multiplication) which is used to calculate composition.