# How do vector and tensor functions work with the chain rule?

Tags: analysis, tensors

I have googled around a LOT about this and also looked in quite a few books, but couldn't find anything at all. Guess with a perfect understanding of tensors one could deduce everything on the fly without trouble, so books don't think it's necessary to mention it, but I'm still struggling with the concept of tensors and often I'm not sure how to handle them.

Suppose we have a function $f(g(x))$ and want to calculate $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$. If $f$, $g$ and $x$ are all scalars, the result is just $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g} \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$. Normal multiplication of two scalars, all good.

However, when one or more of $f$, $g$ and $x$ are vectors and/or second order tensors, I don't know how exactly to apply the chain rule anymore. For example, if $f$ and $g$ are both second order tensors and $x$ is a scalar, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial g}$ becomes a fourth order tensor and $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}$ becomes a second order tensor. But what operation do I use to combine them and get the desired second order tensor $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$?

I guess the perfect answer might be a full table with all 27 possible combinations of scalar/vector/second-order-tensor for each $f$, $g$ and $x$. But an explanation of some patterns, how the underlying principles work and how I can deduce the combinations myself would be great too.

Comment: http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/~pkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/Chapter_1_Vectors_Tensors/Vectors_Tensors_15_Tensor_Calculus_2.pdf, http://cs231n.stanford.edu/vecDerivs.pdf, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2611748/generalization-of-chain-rule-to-tensors etc.

Comment: @JohnDouma The auckland and the SE one don't look very useful to me, but the stanford looks helpful at first glance. Still interested in a more explicit and general answer though.

Comment: How would anyone know what is useful to you? You claim to have googled this and looked in a lot of books but the Stanford one that you say looks useful was the first result in a search for "chain rule for tensors".

Comment: @JohnDouma I feel the question is pretty clear on what would be most useful for me. Anyway, no need to accuse me of "lying" or whatever you're doing just because I didn't try that exact wording.

Comment: What you need to understand 1st is the meaning of what is the derivative of a lineal function then of what is the derivative of a multilinear one. That is readable in the Spivak's "Calculus on Manifolds"

Answer (score 2):

$
\def\a{{G}^\prime_{ij\,pqr}}
\def\b{{F}^\prime_{klm\,ij}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Gij{G_{ij}}
\def\Fklm{F_{klm}}
\def\Xpqr{X_{pqr}}
$Suppose $(F,G,X)$ are high-order tensors and the gradients of the $(f,g)$ functions are known, e.g.
$$\eqalign{
G=g(X) \qiq \a = \grad{\Gij}{\Xpqr} \\
F=f(G) \qiq \b = \grad{\Fklm}{\Gij} \\
}$$
The gradient of the composite function can be found by substituting the differential
of $G$ into the differential of $F$
$$\eqalign{
d\Fklm
 &= \sum_{i,j}\b\:d\Gij \\
 &= \sum_{i,j}\sum_{p,q,r}\b\:\a\:d\Xpqr \\
\grad{\Fklm}{\Xpqr} &= \sum_{i,j}\b\:\a \\
}$$